# "Re-opening" DocuSign "Delivered" envelope in embedded view

Tags: soap, salesforce, docusignapi

My question in a nutshell: Using the SOAP API, is there a way to allow the signer to "Re-open" an envelope that is in Delivered Status (Not expired or completed) in an embedded application?

The details: Using the SalesForce SOAP API examples given here https://github.com/docusign/docusign-soap-sdk (thank you to whoever provided these!), I am having great success creating NEW envelopes. However, using the methods provided in the samples, a brand new envelope is created without regard for existing envelopes. I would like to see if there are any unexpired, delivered envelopes and present that before creating a new one. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any way to fetch an envelope using an Envelope ID (eg: C87908AD-908E-45F6-B4F9-8B6A514XXXXX) and present that to the signer.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was pretty simple. If you know the Envelope ID, you can create a new token that can be used to load the envelope into your app. It looks like this:

```
try {
    token = dsApiSend.RequestRecipientToken(
      document_status.dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c,'1',contact.FirstName + ' ' + contact.LastName,contact.Email,assert,clientURLs);
}  catch ( CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
        envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
}
```